# PhpStorm: add word spacing in functions names

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to add extra spacing between words in method/class/function names in PhpStorm when Camel Case is used?

[image]

Comment: For reference purposes: the same on PhpStorm Forums -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/12292830424466-Add-word-spacing-in-method-class-function-names

Comment: I'm sorry, is this even valid syntax? If not, why do you want to do this (I dont use PHP much anymore but the whole method def seems off with spaces)? The docs say function names should fit this regular expression `^[a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*$`, and your name doesn't work there. Here are the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: @ViaTech There is no actual whitespace in method name provided in question. I want to add spacing not whitespace.  Personally it's much easier to read long method names this way, so I would prefer to have this type of styling of Camel Case in my IDE.

Comment: @ProgZi ah got it...visually you want the IDE to do this spacing.